# How to deal with nested xml-collections in ETL of OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I followed the samples at [OrientDBs manual](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/etl/Extractor.html#xml-extractor) to extract data from a xml collection (2nd sample) and load it into a OrientDB graph database: it worked.

But now i stuck and don't know, how to describe the oetl-configuration (json-File), if I change the samples source data that it looks like (and meets my requirements) - nest a `<ADD>`-Section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <ADD>
           <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
           <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
        </ADD>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <ADD>
           <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
           <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
        </ADD>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Does anybody know, how to write the configuration. The following doesn't work, and the ADD field in my graph database is an empty string:

```
...
   "extractor" :
        { "xml":
           {
              "rootNode": "CATALOG.CD",
              "tagsAsAttribute": ["CATALOG.CD"]
           }
         },
...
```

Thanks for your help!

Best

Comment: I'm  just guessing, could you try with `"tagsAsAttribute": ["CATALOG.CD", "CATALOG.CD.ADD"]` ?